# R - Get all objects into list - with names

Tags: r, list

I have a long list of data-frames with different names. I want to grab them all - and their names into a list.

A short example:

```
sun.data  <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(500, rate=.1), ncol = 5))
wind.data <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(250, rate=.1), ncol = 4))
power.data <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(400, rate=.1), ncol = 3))

mylist <- list(power.data = power.data, sun.data = sun.data, wind.data = wind.data)
```

and not:

```
mylist <- list(power.data, sun.data, wind.data) 
# or
mylist <- list(get(ls()))
```

since I need the names after I have run a few functions and are printing them.

I have tried fiddling around with `get()` and `ls()` but I can't seem to get it to work with the names of the data frames.

Sorry if this is very basic, but I haven't been able to find a answer.

Comment: If you put your data.frames in a list when you create them, you don't need this.

Comment: I load them from different .csv files that are created daily - can start with loading them into a list instead?

Comment: Sure. Usually you'd use `lapply(list.files(<path>, full.names = TRUE), read.csv)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mget`.

Example:

```
sun.data <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2))
wind.data <- data.frame(matrix(1:6, ncol = 3))
power.data <- data.frame(matrix(1:8, ncol = 4))
mylist <- mget(ls(pattern = "\\.data"))
mylist
# $power.data
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
# 1  1  3  5  7
# 2  2  4  6  8
# 
# $sun.data
#   X1 X2
# 1  1  3
# 2  2  4
# 
# $wind.data
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  3  5
# 2  2  4  6
```